# Trouble building an AWS AMI using Packer. Fails with: amazon-ebs: Waiting for SSH to become available

Tags: amazon-web-services

When building an amazon-ebs instance per directions [here](https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/build-image.html) and [here](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html) I built a configuration and encountered this problem.

I found a number of other google searches with similar problems but they didn't help.

What I found was odd - the instance was trying to connect to the private_ip of the spot instance that got launched.

I was seeing something like this:

```
==> amazon-ebs: Using ssh communicator to connect: 172.31.8.223
==> amazon-ebs: Waiting for SSH to become available...
```

Since I was not on the same local area network there's no route to connect to that address and eventually I got this error. I checked the instance on the dashboard - sure enough it was created and had a valid IP address. I was able to log into it but for some reason packer tries to connect to the private address.

```
'amazon-ebs' errored: Timeout waiting for SSH.
```

For what it's worth my configuration file was something like this:

```
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
      "ami_name": "{{user `ami_name`}}",
      "instance_type": "{{user `aws_instance_type`}}",
      "region": "{{user `aws_region`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
      "source_ami": "{{user `aws_ami_image`}}",
      "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
      "spot_price": "0.20",
      "tags": {
        "Name": "{{user `ami_name`}}-{{user `image_version`}}",
        "OS_Version": "Ubuntu XYZ",
        "Release": "XYZ",
        "Description": "Ubuntu XYZ AMI for Me"
      },
      "user_data_file": "config/user-data.sh"
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was fixed by adding the [ssh_interface](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#ssh_interface) option into the `amazon-ebs` builder portion of my packer.json file:

It's unclear why this is necessary but packer started working for me once I did this. My resulting config looked something like this:

```
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "ssh_interface": "public_ip",
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
      "ami_name": "{{user `ami_name`}}",
      "instance_type": "{{user `aws_instance_type`}}",
      "region": "{{user `aws_region`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
      "source_ami": "{{user `aws_ami_image`}}",
      "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
      "spot_price": "0.20",
      "tags": {
        "Name": "{{user `ami_name`}}-{{user `image_version`}}",
        "OS_Version": "Ubuntu XYZ",
        "Release": "XYZ",
        "Description": "Ubuntu XYZ AMI for Me"
      },
      "user_data_file": "config/user-data.sh"
    }
  ],
```